# Getting exception when using DateTime.Parse method

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, timezone

So, i have this string "Date: Mon Jan 03 2011 19:29:44 GMT+0200", and when i use **DateTime.Parse(date).ToString();** i'm getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

If i remove the '+0200' part it works ok, but ofcourse it doesn't show the correct local time.
What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), it seems that `DateTime.Parse()` only understands:

- The `GMT` designator, used alone, e.g. `Mon, Jan 03 2011 17:29:44 GMT`, or
- A time zone offset specified without the `GMT` designator, e.g. `Mon, Jan 03 2011 19:29:44+02:00`.

You might want to convert your date string to the second form.

Answer (score 4):

It just means that the time zone offset isn't an expected part of the default format strings.

If you know what format you're expecting, I suggest you call [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) (or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)), specifying the format(s) to try. Look at the documentation for [custom date/time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @user361633: Don't forget you can provide multiple patterns - I'd expect you to know at least a *range* of expected formats.

Answer (score 2):

You have two mistakes.

First - don`t use Parse method. More correct is TryParse.
Second - you will have globalisation issues, when you use Parse or TryParse without arguments.

For example, see this code:

DateTime.Parse( "01.02.2011" ); In the USA it is 2nd of January. In the Germany it is 1st of February.

So, I recomment you to use formats from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DATETIME.PARSEEXACT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true).